# Neon-Animated-Pages Animation Size with Polymer

Tags: polymer

I'm working on an app using Polymer. This app uses `neon-animated-pages` to move between views and tabs. I have a [Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/17HpodEy2fZctAeBEkfb?p=preview). Some relevant code can be seen here:

```
<div style="width:33%; background-color:lightgrey;">
  <paper-button on-click="onItem1Click">Item 1</paper-button>
  <paper-button on-click="onItem2Click">Item 2</paper-button>
  <paper-button on-click="onItem3Click">Item 3</paper-button>
  <br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>

<div id="contentArea" style="width:67%; padding:12px;">
  <neon-animated-pages selected="[[ selectedIndex ]]" entry-animation="slide-left-animation" exit-animation="slide-left-animation">
    <section>
      <item-1></item-1>
    </section>

    <section>
      <item-2></item-2>
    </section>

    <section>
      <h4>Item 3</h4>
      <p>This is information for item #3.</p>
    </section>
  </neon-animated-pages>
</div>
```

When I click a `paper-button` or `paper-tab`, some new content gets animated in. However, as the content is leaving, it animates to the left on top of the grey navigation area. I want the content to animate to the left. However,I do not want it to cover "Item 1", "Item 2", and "Item 3" in the process. Its like the `neon-animated-pages` element uses the whole screen for animations instead of just the area its confined to, which in this case would be the "contentArea" `div`. I'm not sure how to fix this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/LOqnbtdZJkr0xIgxsOyM?p=preview

Add `overflow-x: hidden;` to your 67% width `div`.

I had encountered the same problem on [this codepen](http://codepen.io/dsschnau/pen/6571d1173b1c9c09191bdf694556103c) a while back. Note the commented-out overflow-x on line 7 of the css file.

Answer (score 0):

Add z-index to both container divs like so.

```
<div style="width:33%; background-color:lightgrey; z-index:1;"></div>
<div id="contentArea" style="width:67%; padding:12px; z-index:0"></div>
```

You could also put it your css in a style tag within that Polymer element to separate your html from your css.